# This page is trying to load scripts from unauthorized sources

Tags: https, ssl-certificate

After installing ssl certification in the website, it is showing a shield symbol with a warning "This page is trying to load scripts from unauthorized sources". How to resolve the issues? Should i change all the http to https through out the project or any other ways are there to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

If you are loading a page on HTTPS all resources should be loaded using HTTPS. No resources will be allowed to load using HTTP if the page was loaded on HTTPS.

Answer (score 0):

This is expected behavior,  When your site is hosted with SSL and you are consuming resources the without SSL(i.e. http) than the warning will be shown.

Answer (score 0):

You can handle such scenario by putting URLs without protocol like

```
//www.example.com
```

It will automatically take protocol of host.

Comment: Although this will work it's important to remember that if the site you are getting resources from doesn't support HTTPS this will fail.

Comment: Yeah If we have resources from other domain then it should be in HTTPS only. As it works in both cases i.e. HTTP and HTTPS